# Can you get an issue's priority in a Github milestone with the REST API?

Tags: json, rest, github

Github lets you [prioritize issues in a milestone](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/about-milestones#prioritizing-issues-and-pull-requests-in-milestones).  Is there any way to get that information with the Github REST API?

For example, this query

```
https://api.github.com/repos/criesbeck/workit/issues
```

for the issues for [this milestone](https://github.com/criesbeck/workit/milestone/1) returns no clue that I can see that the issue "User can control with voice commands" is the sixth issue in the milestone. Am I missing it?

```
[ ...
{
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/criesbeck/workit/issues/3",
    "repository_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/criesbeck/workit",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/criesbeck/workit/issues/3/labels{/name}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/criesbeck/workit/issues/3/comments",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/criesbeck/workit/issues/3/events",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/criesbeck/workit/issues/3",
    "id": 852867677,
    "node_id": "MDU6SXNzdWU4NTI4Njc2Nzc=",
    "number": 3,
    "title": "User can control with voice commands",
    "user": {
      "login": "criesbeck",
      "id": 1717574,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE3MTc1NzQ=",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1717574?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/criesbeck",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "labels": [
      {
        "id": 2893844412,
        "node_id": "MDU6TGFiZWwyODkzODQ0NDEy",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/criesbeck/workit/labels/enhancement",
        "name": "enhancement",
        "color": "a2eeef",
        "default": true,
        "description": "New feature or request"
      },
      {
        "id": 2893865786,
        "node_id": "MDU6TGFiZWwyODkzODY1Nzg2",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/criesbeck/workit/labels/size:%205",
        "name": "size: 5",
        "color": "E96C70",
        "default": false,
        "description": "5 story points"
      }
    ],
    "state": "open",
    "locked": false,
    "assignee": null,
    "assignees": [

    ],
    "milestone": {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/criesbeck/workit/milestones/1",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/criesbeck/workit/milestone/1",
      "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/criesbeck/workit/milestones/1/labels",
      "id": 6637701,
      "node_id": "MDk6TWlsZXN0b25lNjYzNzcwMQ==",
      "number": 1,
      "title": "Final demo",
      "description": "",
      "creator": {
        "login": "criesbeck",
        "id": 1717574,
        "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE3MTc1NzQ=",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1717574?v=4",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/criesbeck",
        "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck/followers",
        "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck/following{/other_user}",
        "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck/gists{/gist_id}",
        "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
        "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck/subscriptions",
        "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck/orgs",
        "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck/repos",
        "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck/events{/privacy}",
        "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/criesbeck/received_events",
        "type": "User",
        "site_admin": false
      },
      "open_issues": 6,
      "closed_issues": 0,
      "state": "open",
      "created_at": "2021-04-08T01:00:22Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-04-08T01:03:44Z",
      "due_on": "2021-04-29T07:00:00Z",
      "closed_at": null
    },
    "comments": 0,
    "created_at": "2021-04-07T22:16:01Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-04-08T01:01:54Z",
    "closed_at": null,
    "author_association": "OWNER",
    "active_lock_reason": null,
    "body": "",
    "performed_via_github_app": null
  },
  ...]
```